# While creating a password for an Admin user, I get a scary message "will lose all EFS-encrypted files, personal certs & stored passwords"

Tags: windows, windows-10, passwords

I have a personal Windows 10 Laptop which runs

```
Edition Windows 10 Home Single Language
Version 21H2
Installed on    ‎11-‎04-‎2021
OS build    19044.2006
Experience  Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.4180.0
```

From the beginning, I have been running it will an Admin Level local user, which is not password protected. Now I am planning to give the laptop to some vendors, so I wanted to set a password for this user & give a 2nd standard user password to the repair guy.

When I try to create a password for my original user, I get the following scary message

[image]

What exactly does this mean? Will I lose all the cached passwords on my Firefox Browser? Or Edge? or what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically – you will lose everything that was protected using Windows' Data Protection API (DPAPI), which would use your login password to unlock the master encryption key. Examples:

- Everything in the "Credential Manager" Control Panel section is protected using DPAPI. (However, the "Web Credentials" subsection there is pretty much just Internet Explorer – it is not used by Chrome/Edge nor Firefox, both of which use their own databases.)
- Certificates in `certmgr.msc` are also DPAPI-protected, which might include certificates used to connect to your work VPN, or the certificate used for EFS file encryption. (EFS is the "Encrypt this file" checkbox in a file's Properties dialog.)
- Chrome/Edge *do* use DPAPI to protect their stored password databases, but someone has said earlier that they use "machine scope" protection which isn't tied to your Windows account personally.

  Firefox/Mozilla do not use DPAPI as far as I know, but this may change in the future.
- The software-based "Windows Hello" WebAuthn token most likely uses DPAPI.
- The ssh-agent component of OpenSSH for Windows uses DPAPI to protect the SSH private keys that were loaded using ssh-add.
- Dropbox encrypts its entire configuration file using DPAPI – you will not lose your files, but you will need to re-login and re-setup sync (and wait for it to reindex everything).

But you can avoid all of this by *not* going through the administrative password reset feature. Instead have the user change their own password – that is, you need to **log in** as the user whose password you want to change, then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Del</kbd> and use the "Change a password" option. In this mode, both the old and new passwords are provided to the OS so it can properly re-encrypt the DPAPI master keys.

Comment: Thank you very much. This worked just fine.